# String passing between functions in VC++ SDI application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, listview, mfc, sdi

I am doing an project in SDI. I have two functions name sendtext(CString str) and 
displaytext(CString inr) both in different class.
 I have a pointer name pView to send the string str to function "displaytext".
 The problem is after some operations i get a text in str and i send that text to display text in the output screen i get the text and wen the second text comes to "displaytext" the former text disappears and the latest string only present. Pleae help me like how can i display both the text in the output window on ClistCtrl class.

```
Void sendtext()
{
 CTreeCtrl&  trCtrl = GetTreeCtrl(); 
 HTREEITEM hItem,hsc; 
 CExerciseDoc *pDoc = GetDocument();

 CString pathname,strLine; 
 CString filename;
 CFileDialog dlg(TRUE);
 dlg.DoModal();
 if(dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
 {
     pathname=dlg.GetPathName(); // return full path and filename
 }

CStdioFile File;

if(File.Open(pathname, CFile::modeRead)) // Open file to be read 
{ 
   while(File.ReadString(strLine)) // Read file 
   { 
     int Position = 0; 
     CString Token; 

     CAtlString str(strLine);
     CAtlString resToken,resToken1;

     resToken = str.Tokenize(_T("-:, "), Position); 
     pDoc->pSendview->displaytext(resToken);
     if(resToken != (_T(""))) // Empty File Check

     hItem = trCtrl.InsertItem(resToken , 0, 2 );

     while(resToken!="") 
     { 
        resToken = str.Tokenize(_T("-:@, "), Position);
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
void CRightView::displaytext(CAtlString league)
{
   CListCtrl &ctlRightView = this->GetListCtrl();
   ResetLeagues();
   CAtlString resToken;
   ctlRightView.InsertColumn(1,  _T("First "),   LVCFMT_LEFT,   80);
   ctlRightView.InsertColumn(1,  _T("Second "),   LVCFMT_LEFT,   80);

   int nItem;
  nItem = ctlRightView.InsertItem(0,  league);
  ctlRightView.SetItemText(nItem, 1,  league);
}
```

The text file contains the following contents

**man-woman**

**brother-sister**

Let me explain you. In the sendtext() i open a text file  after opening i tokenize it and the tokenized output is resToken which is sent to displaytext() via

```
pDoc->pLeftView->displaytext(resToken);
```

and when i run in the client window when i run the app i am getting the text "man" and it goes for empty file check and after the while loop is broken it comes to the same tokenizing area and starts tokenizes the new line in the text file say brother-sister and tokenized output is sent to displaytext via the same piece of code mentioned above.

On the client window i am getting the thing as "brother" i dont see "man" .. i want both the "man and brother" to be displayed as

First(Column name)

brother

man

Comment: Be more explicit and provide more code.

Comment: Hey pls look at the code this is what  i hav done till now

Comment: OK, please edit your question in order to: 1) format your source code so that is readable by indenting it correctly). 2) provide a sample of the contents of the file in pathname . 3) describe how the list control should look like with the file provided at point 2).

Comment: Hey Mich please have a look i have edited according to ur explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of List control also you are calling the

> nItem = ctlRightView.InsertItem(0,  league);

Here nItem will be the same value each time you call this.So you are overwriting the previous content by the call

> ctlRightView.SetItemText(nItem, 1,  league);

Instead each time you have to insert to the next position of the list. So use a variable as current position and call:

> int nItem = 0;
>
> nItem = ctlRightView.InsertItem(Position++,  league);
>
> ctlRightView.SetItemText(nItem, 1,  league);

You may declare position as a global variable

Comment: i dont have a problem with tree control please comment on my problem in list control